# ROS and 4g/3g modem use

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone ever tried using ROS with 4G/3G communications? I have a 4G modem that is connected. When I start up my launch file, it seems to block, then after about 5 mins whatever it was doing times out and the launch file continues to begin to launch my actual ROS nodes. When I am using a wlan connection, it instantly launches the ROS nodes. Is the blocking because it really is searching for a way to use wlan vs some other method of communication? If it helps, I am using pppd to launch the 4g modem in Ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11975/ros-and-4g/3g-modem-use/) by [GuMiBears](https://answers.ros.org/users/1401/gumibears/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would assume that it has something to do with port configurations and what your service provider allows/doesn't allow.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuMiBears](https://answers.ros.org/users/1401/gumibears/) on 2011-11-19**:
So its actually roscore that blocks. Once roscore is up and running roslaunch works instantly. Also once everything is running, 4g works just fine. Does it block because it wants to use a specific port that service provider doesnt allow?